# What is causing the error in my CruiseControl.Net Project?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I'm a bit baffled by the results I'm seeing in my CruiseControl.Net build log. The build fails after a few minutes but I can't figure out what's causing it.

```
 <cruisecontrol project="Bromley Live">
  <request source="ITUSER-PC" buildCondition="ForceBuild">Build (ForceBuild) triggered from ITUSER-PC</request>
  <parameters>
    <parameter name="CCNetForceBuildReason" value="Debugging" />
    <parameter name="$CCNetArtifactDirectory" value="C:\CCNet\Projects\Bromley Live\Artifacts" />
    <parameter name="$CCNetBuildCondition" value="ForceBuild" />
    <parameter name="$CCNetBuildDate" value="2011-06-02" />
    <parameter name="$CCNetBuildTime" value="14:34:38" />
    <parameter name="$CCNetFailureUsers" value="System.Collections.ArrayList" />
    <parameter name="$CCNetIntegrationStatus" value="Unknown" />
    <parameter name="$CCNetLabel" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <parameter name="$CCNetLastIntegrationStatus" value="Failure" />
    <parameter name="$CCNetListenerFile" value="C:\CCNet\Projects\Bromley Live\Artifacts\Bromley Live_ListenFile.xml" />
    <parameter name="$CCNetModifyingUsers" value="System.Collections.ArrayList" />
    <parameter name="$CCNetNumericLabel" value="0" />
    <parameter name="$CCNetProject" value="Bromley Live" />
    <parameter name="$CCNetProjectUrl" value="http://CIBuildServer/CruiseControl/server/local/project/Bromley Live/ViewProjectReport.aspx" />
    <parameter name="$CCNetRequestSource" value="OCL-DEV-WEB" />
    <parameter name="$CCNetUser" value="" />
    <parameter name="$CCNetWorkingDirectory" value="C:\CCNet\Projects\Bromley Live\WorkingDirectory" />
  </parameters>
  <modifications />
  <integrationProperties>
    <CCNetArtifactDirectory>C:\CCNet\Projects\Bromley Live\Artifacts</CCNetArtifactDirectory>
    <CCNetBuildCondition>ForceBuild</CCNetBuildCondition>
    <CCNetBuildDate>2011-06-02</CCNetBuildDate>
    <CCNetBuildTime>14:34:38</CCNetBuildTime>
    <CCNetFailureUsers />
    <CCNetIntegrationStatus>Failure</CCNetIntegrationStatus>
    <CCNetLabel>1.0.0.0</CCNetLabel>
    <CCNetLastIntegrationStatus>Failure</CCNetLastIntegrationStatus>
    <CCNetListenerFile>C:\CCNet\Projects\Bromley Live\Artifacts\Bromley Live_ListenFile.xml</CCNetListenerFile>
    <CCNetModifyingUsers />
    <CCNetNumericLabel>0</CCNetNumericLabel>
    <CCNetProject>Bromley Live</CCNetProject>
    <CCNetProjectUrl>http://CIBuildServer/CruiseControl/server/local/project/Bromley Live/ViewProjectReport.aspx</CCNetProjectUrl>
    <CCNetRequestSource>ITUSER-PC</CCNetRequestSource>
    <CCNetWorkingDirectory>C:\CCNet\Projects\Bromley Live\WorkingDirectory</CCNetWorkingDirectory>
    <LastIntegrationStatus>Failure</LastIntegrationStatus>
    <LastSuccessfulIntegrationLabel>UNKNOWN</LastSuccessfulIntegrationLabel>
    <LastModificationDate>01/06/2011 14:35:34</LastModificationDate>
    <CCNetForceBuildReason>Debugging</CCNetForceBuildReason>
  </integrationProperties>
  <build date="2011-06-02 14:34:38" buildtime="00:00:56" error="true" buildcondition="ForceBuild">

<buildresults>
  <message>The command completed successfully.</message>
</buildresults>


<buildresults>
  <message>-------------------------------------------------------------------------------</message>
  <message>   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              </message>
  <message>-------------------------------------------------------------------------------</message>
  <message>  Started : Thu Jun 02 14:34:38 2011</message>
  <message>   Source : C:\CCNet\Projects\Bromley Live\WorkingDirectory\Website\</message>
  <message>     Dest : \\LiveServer\wwwroot$\Bromley\</message>
  <message>    Files : *.*</message>
  <message>     </message>
  <message>Exc Files : Thumbs.db</message>
  <message>     *.scc</message>
  <message>     </message>
  <message> Exc Dirs : .hg</message>
  <message>     </message>
  <message>  Options : *.* /NS /NC /NDL /S /E /COPY:DAT /NP /XO /XA:H /R:1000000 /W:30 </message>
  <message>------------------------------------------------------------------------------</message>
  <message>             \\LiveServer\wwwroot$\Bromley\admin\legacy\selfAssessment\uploadVisitReport.asp</message>
  <message>             \\LiveServer\wwwroot$\Bromley\Bin\AjaxControlToolkit.pdb</message>
  <message>             C:\CCNet\Projects\Bromley Live\WorkingDirectory\Website\userControls\IconMenuTopControl.ascx</message>
  <message>             C:\CCNet\Projects\Bromley Live\WorkingDirectory\Website\userControls\IconMenuTopControl.ascx.vb</message>
  <message>------------------------------------------------------------------------------</message>
  <message>               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras</message>
  <message>    Dirs :       212         0       212         0         0        16</message>
  <message>   Files :      1804        45      1759         0         0       203</message>
  <message>   Bytes :   44.46 m    2.89 m   41.57 m         0         0    2.03 m</message>
  <message>   Times :   0:00:55   0:00:16                       0:00:00   0:00:39</message>
  <message>   Speed :              185068 Bytes/sec.</message>
  <message>   Speed :              10.589 MegaBytes/min.</message>
  <message>   Ended : Thu Jun 02 14:35:34 2011</message>
</buildresults>
</build>
</cruisecontrol>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Robocopy does not return proper exit status codes (that is, 0 on success). To work around this, you have to use the `successExitCodes` attibute on your [executable task](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Executable+Task). Setting it to "0,1,2" should work (you want the task to fail on other results). ([Robocopy exit codes list](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html) as a reference.)

Comment: I had successExitCodes 1,0 - updating that to 0,1,2 sorted it out. Many thanks